# Viewing Predictive Intelligence Collect Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We've implemented the **Collect** tracking code (not to be confused with Web Collect) accessible from Analytics Builder menu > Web & Mobile Analytics app > Configure Data Source (cog icon). Refer to screenshot below.

[image: Collect Code]

This works well; if we add this tracking code to a web page and view the web page, we immediately see the web page visit on the location tile (on the Web & Mobile Analytics Dashboard).

I see that this feature operates similar to Google Analytics in that:

> Predictive Intelligence monitors the behavior of your website traffic via a JavaScript installation. We collect page views, which will potentially give you:
>
> - Browser Type
> - User Location
> - Session Time and Length
> - Page URL
> - Page Title
> - Referring Site

The question I have is, where is this data actually stored? We can see the data in chart format on the Web & Mobile Analytics Dashboard, but I can't figure out where to view and download this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliot, I don't have first hand knowledge of this.  But, I've been told PI data is written to hidden data extensions.  Support can make them available upon request.  In my scenario, the data extension began with the name "IGO_".  No sure if that is always the case.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I've retrieved all Data Extensions using the SOAP API and I see [these Data Extensions](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/676dace211b1b2626c4b83ee8dbbe3a7) appear in a 'PI and IGO' Data Extension folder.